# Add text value alongside each "slide" in jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slideshow

I currently have a **jQuery Slider** in progress: http://jsfiddle.net/hQj8a/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('body').removeClass('no-js');

        $('#my-carousel-2').carousel({

            itemsPerPage: 3,

            itemsPerTransition: 3,

            speed: 500,

            nextPrevLinks: false

        });

    });
```

When the user clicks between the pagination (1,2,3) I would like different text to display next to the pagination.
So initially on page load (i.e. state **1**) it should say 'hello' and clicking **2**, it should say 'hello again' and **3** it says 'goodbye'.

Can someone show me how this is possible with my current code? It doesn't have to "animate" but just switch between the three bits of text depending on the current pagination value.

Many thanks for any pointers with this :-)

Comment: what version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: Hi Cory. Sorry, should have said. It's 1.4.2. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hQj8a/5/

Within jQuery, I added a span to hold the text "Hello" "Hello again" or "Goodbye". I gave that span an id of "addedText". Then I added an event listener for the pagination links (found the selector using inspect element in chrome), that looks at the text of clicked links in order to determines which link you clicked. Based on that, fill the addedText appropriately.

Added jQuery/javascript:

```
$('.pagination-links').append("<span id='addedText'>Hello</span>");
var addedText = document.getElementById('addedText');

$('.pagination-links a').click(function(){
    if (this.innerHTML == '1')
        addedText.innerHTML = "Hello";
    else if (this.innerHTML == '3')
        addedText.innerHTML = "Goodbye";
    else
        addedText.innerHTML = "Hello again";
});
```

Added CSS:

```
#addedText {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 12px; //copied from .carousel .pagination-links li a
}
```

Edit: Added "Hello" to addedText by default, so it displays on page load.

Comment: That is almost 100% brilliance. My only slight nag is that when the page initially loads No.1("Hello") isn't displayed. Is this an easy fix? Many thanks for your help and patience here. Very much appreciated :D

Comment: I just realized that too haha. I added it, check out the first line of the jQuery code. I just added `Hello` inside of the `<span id='addedText'></span>` I updated the fiddle and edited the answer.

Comment: Many, many thanks Cory. Utterly brilliant help. Thanks again.